# Broken pipe error for generating figures in Django

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I'm testing a Django app running locally using the test server.

One of my views returns a dictionary to its template, `main.html`:

```
d = {'f1':'/f1.png','f2':'/f2.png'}
return render_to_response('myapp/main.html', d, context)
```

Each url (e.g., `'/f1.png'`) in `d` will generate and return a figure:

```
canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
response=HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
canvas.print_png(response,dpi=400)
return response
```

There are no errors in either view that generate the figures.

But, second figure sometimes fails to render on the main page (`main.html`).

When this occurs, I get the following error from the test server:

```
"GET /url_for_my_app/f2.png HTTP/1.1" 500 59
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I realize this may be due to browser-request timing (e.g., [error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560259/error-errno-32-broken-pipe)).

(1) What may cause the error in this case?

(2) How is it best addressed?

Edit: I identified the apparent cause (but only empirically --- I don't know why it causes the error). The view that generates the second figure included `plt.tight_layout()` prior to returning the `fig` object (residual from running in notebook). The error goes away when `plt.tight_layout()` is removed.

```
plt.tight_layout()
canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
response=HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
canvas.print_png(response,dpi=400)
return response
```