# using jquery ajax in django project

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I try to post form use jquery ajax
**my script was like this**

```
<script src="{% static "jquery/jquery.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                 data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
            });
            $('#comment_form form').submit(function(){
                name = $("#id_name").val();
                email = $("#id_email").val();
                content = $("#id_comment").val();
                $.post("{% url 'blog:comments_upload' %}",
                        {
                            name:name,
                            email:email,
                            content:content,
                        },
                function(data, status){
                    alert("数据" + data + "\n状态" + status);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**and my view**

```
def comments_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "it's a test"
        print str(request.POST)
        return HttpResponse("test")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("<h1>test</h1>")
```

**I can get the test data through print request.POST**

```
<QueryDict: {u'content': [u'test'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'V85BdVwzGY3NUglVfNt4dBWJB0ROQmpv'], u'name': [u'bricks'], u'email': [u'252142844@qq.com']}>
```

**but then it comes an error**
I can get a elegantly result by using a button click, but once a submit with a form, it simply doesn't work

```
  [11/Apr/2015 00:18:07] "POST /comments_upload/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 212, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 270, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 194, in send_preamble
    'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
[11/Apr/2015 00:18:07] "POST /comments_upload/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 35960)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7-py2.7.egg/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 129, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
[11/Apr/2015 00:18:07] "POST /detail/5/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11797
```

Comment: Could be your issue is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560259/error-errno-32-broken-pipe)

Comment: well can you see any problem via this issue?

Comment: There were a couple of possible solutions there which is why I linked to it. Post your form code.