# How to handle Broken pipe errors with Flask/gunicorn?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, broken-pipe

I have a Flask API that is being run by gunicorn. To my knowledge and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31504987/7981821) SO link gunicorn should be handling any Broken pipe errors automatically for me which is why this error is confusing to me. Whenever the user hits the API endpoint a call to a MySQL database is made with SQLAlchemy. I suspect that the SQLAlchemy connection is remaining open after a query but I had trouble verifying that information. I have found the following error signals in the logs for the application but have had difficulty reproducing the behaviour myself.

```
[INFO] Handling signal: term 
[17] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 17) 
[16] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 16) 
[24] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 24) 
[18] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18) 
[19] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19) 
[22] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 22) 
[23] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 23) 
[20] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 20) 
[21] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 21) 
[1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master 
ERROR:sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool:Exception during reset or similar
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Why might this behaviour not be handled when a user disconnects prematurely and how would I verify what connections remain open on the program terminating?

Answer (score 0):

The log says your Gunicorn is receiving the termination signal. There's nothing to really handle as things are dying.

Gunicorn will handle a broken pipe if it happens during a regular request.

Comment: Why is the broken pipe error happening in that case? Shouldn't everything be shut down if gunicorn receives a term signal?

Comment: That's probably the Sqlalchemy pool to your database getting shut down, not the client connection Gunicorn manages.

Comment: How would I verify/fix that?

Comment: Is this a connection or session issue

Comment: There is no issue if anything doesn't seem broken.